# Speeding up flite TTS in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, text-to-speech

I understand that it may be possible to speed up flite TTS in iOS by removing unused voices.  How is this done?

I have some text that seems to take about 45 seconds to convert (on iPhone 3G) but I only have 30 seconds.  I am starting the conversion as soon as possible and preloading the AV player already but I am still a little too slow.

Comment: Out of interest how long was your text?

Comment: Usually about 20-40 words.  You can check out the free app.  It is called "Robot DJ" on the iTunes Store.  I like it but it never caught on.

Comment: Hehe, that's actually really good. Funny and good for a quick tour of music I don't know. Gave you 5*. I'd take the ad off until you get some word of mouth.

Answer (score 2):

This trick will not really speed up flite but will free up the device to do other things while flite is doing it's thing:
Add this method:

```
- (void)speak:(NSString *)message {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
    [fliteEngine speakText:message];    
    [pool release];
}
```

When you want ti to speak, call it with this:

```
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(speak:) withObject:@"Text to speak!"];
```

This will put your app into multi-treaded mode and will render the speech and play it as a background thread.  This will allow your app to go off and do other things while this is happening.  I have also noticed that it seems to render the text a little faster this way.  Hopefully it will give you the little bit you need.

Comment: Thanks, I am already threading - it did save a few seconds.  Did you ever hear of removing voices to speed up Flite TTS - I don't really understand why that would work but several posts have said that it does.

Answer (score 1):

Removing voices makes no difference in the speed.  One voice,  "cmu_us_kal" is much faster than the others.  I did not perform speed tests on all of the others but kal is at least 5 times faster than "cmu_us_rms" which I had been using.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert in shorter sentences or phrases.  Then start playing one converted speech segment while still converting the rest in a background thread.

Comment: Thanks - I should have mentioned that I have to speak something every 30 seconds and it is taking me 45 seconds to process each one.  The speaking takes about 10 seconds so your method will get me closer.  Do you think processing two short strings is faster than one twice as long or will it be a little slower?